# Silverlight - how do I get the text of the selected item in a combobox

Tags: silverlight, combobox

Easy one for you all...

I'm new to Silverlight and really missing stuff like DataTables and things. What I'm also currently struggling with is how to get the text of my combobox's currently selected item.
In winforms I would have done:

```
ComboBox myCombo = new ComboBox.......
string selected = myCombo.Text;
```

I'm struggling how to get this info out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The selected item of your combo box is whatever type of item is currently holding.  So if you set the binding to a collection of strings, then the selected item will be a string:

```
string mySelectedValue = ((string)MyComboBox.SelectedItem);
```

If it is a more complex object you will need to cast and use the expected object.  If you have XAML using the list box item class, like:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox">
    <ComboBox.Items>
        <ComboBoxItem>
            <TextBlock Text="Hello World"/>
        </ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox.Items>
</ComboBox>
```

Then you would access the selected item like this:

```
string mySelectedValue = 
  ((TextBlock)((ComboBoxItem)MyComboBox.SelectedItem).Content).Text;
```

Comment: I think Calanus is straight forward answer to the question

Comment: My answer is 3 years old.  I haven't been in Silverlight for a while so it is plausible that Calanus's answer might work in the current version of Silverlight; I cannot comment on that.  I don't think it did for rich combo box items like the one described here when I replied.

Comment: Doesnt work on latest silverlight. got "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem' to type 'System.String'."

Answer (score 7):

Right, the answer is to use `myCombo.SelectionBoxItem.ToString()`

Answer (score 3):

For a complex object, use reflection with the DisplayMemberPath property:

```
var itemType = cbx.SelectedItem.GetType();
var pi = itemType.GetProperty(cbx.DisplayMemberPath);
var stringValue = pi.GetValue(cbx.SelectedItem, null).ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Your solution is the one that works in all situation

Answer (score 3):

```
((ComboBoxItem)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Content.ToString()
```

I got it worked by this statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
string txt=(comboboxID.SelectedItem as BindingClass).Text.ToString();

string value=(comboboxID.SelectedItem as BindingClass).Value.ToString();


 public class BindingClass
 {
     public string Text
       {
         set;
          get;
      }

     public string Value
       {
         set;
          get;
      }
 }
```

Comment: Private set; will set the property field in private.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a simple combobox for an array of strings, you can get the selected string using

```
(string)e.AddedItems[0];
```

Suppose I have a product list combo and I want to know the selected product name. So in the SelectionChanged Event I write the following code:

```
private void productCombo_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string product_type=(string)e.AddedItems[0];
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
myCombo.SelectedItem.Content
```

will return the content of the ComboBoxItem.  This could be a TextBlock, etc. depending on what you have in there, and what you are using for an item template.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work 1) because SelectedItem isn't a string and 2) even if you do .ToString() on it then it returns System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem. I know I can probably parse this and get the info out but surely there is an easier way?