# How to get combobox selected item text in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight

Anyone tell me the correct syntax for getting combobox selected item text in silverlight.

Comment: can you show your `XAML` code for combobox ?

Answer (score 0):

`string selectedCountry = cbCountry.SelectedItem.ToString();`

and try this

[Silverlight - how do I get the text of the selected item in a combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868511/silverlight-how-do-i-get-the-text-of-the-selected-item-in-a-combobox)